# How do you turn a list of strings into a list of sublists with each string in each sublist?

Tags: python, string, list, sublist

How do you turn a list of strings into a list of sublist of strings?

For example:

```
List_of_Strings = ['abc','def','ghi']
```

Desired Output:

```
[['abc'],['def'],['ghi']]
```

My hack to get it is:

```
List_of_Sublist_of_Strings = [(str(x)+",").split(",") for x in List_of_Strings]
```

Produces:

```
[['abc', ''], ['def', ''], ['ghi', '']]
```

This produces an unwanted empty item in the sublists, but perhaps it's not possible to create a list of sublists in which the sublists only have one item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put those strings in `[]` there, and  it's done.

```
>>> lis =  ['abc','def','ghi']
>>> [[x] for x in lis]
[['abc'], ['def'], ['ghi']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
>>> lst = ['abc','def','ghi']
>>> [[x] for x in lst]
[['abc'], ['def'], ['ghi']]
>>>
```

Putting `x` in `[]` places it in a list of its own.