# Need to create a list of 100 sublists that contain 3 random values each

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm currently trying to create a list that is 100 items long, with each item being a sublist with 3 values.

These values are being generated by **randint(0,1000)**, with each value of each sublist being unique.
For example, if x1list = [1,2,3], x2list = [4,5,6], and x3list = [7,8,9]... I want **testlist** to contain **[[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]**.

Here is my code so far, I'm new to programming so I apologize in advance if it is inefficient/basic.

```
import random
from random import randint

x1list = []
x2list = []
x3list = []
sublist = []

for i in range(100):
    x1list.append(randint(0,1000))
    x2list.append(randint(0,1000))
    x3list.append(randint(0,1000))

n = 0
for i in range(100):
    sublist.append(x1list[n])
    sublist.append(x2list[n])
    sublist.append(x3list[n])

    n += 1

testlist = [[value] for value in sublist]
```

The goal is to get the **testlist** to be the final 100 length list containing 100 sublists of length 3, as described previously. However, currently the list comprehension I have with testlist gives me a list of length 300, with each item in **testlist** being a random integer value that is *it's own list*.

Another solution I tried with list comprehension got me somewhat closer to my end goal, but with a different problem...

Replacing the **testlist** list comprehension line with this instead:

```
testlist = [[x, y, z] for x in x1list for y in x2list for z in x3list]
```

Yielded **testlist** containing sublists of 3 values each, however **testlist** was *1000000* items in length and was seemingly only changing 1 value (x, y *or* z, not all 3) per each sublist.

Any idea on how to get the desired result for this? I've checked some other stackoverflow posts and they've helped me somewhat in getting to this point, but I've sort of hit a wall on this.

Here are the posts I viewed to get me to this point:

[How do you turn a list of strings into a list of sublists with each string in each sublist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337331/how-do-you-turn-a-list-of-strings-into-a-list-of-sublists-with-each-string-in-ea)

[Python Create a list of sublists from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089654/python-create-a-list-of-sublists-from-a-list)

[Creating Sublists from a “List”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542593/creating-sublists-from-a-list) - This last one did not help me very much as I could not get **zip()** to work.

Thanks in advance for any help you're able to provide!

Comment: You just want `[[randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(100)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` the 3 lists together:

```py
import random
from random import randint

x1list = []
x2list = []
x3list = []

for i in range(100):
    x1list.append(randint(0,1000))
    x2list.append(randint(0,1000))
    x3list.append(randint(0,1000))

sublist = list(map(list, zip(x1list, x2list, x3list)))
print(sublist)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try list comprehension

```
from random import randint
mylist = [[randint(0,1000),randint(0,100),randint(0,1000)] for x in range(100)]
print(mylist)
```